# 404 page not found despite correct config

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, web-applications

I have a simple web application that runs on Tomcat.
The first page opened after I run the app from IntelliJ is the page from index.html
There user click on button and is redirected to dashboard page. It looks like this in index.html:

```
<a href="dashboard"> <button id="enter" type="button"> ENTER </button> </a>
```

I have a servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/dashboard")
public class DashboardServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("html/dashboard.html");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And I have dashboard.html file located in web/html/dashboard.html

After user clicks on button on first page, he is redirected to the next page (the dashboard page) but I see only 404 instead of page.

I cannot find what is wrong here. To solve the problem I added this to my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>DashboardServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>airport.flight.control.servlet.DashboardServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DashboardServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dashboard</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

It gave me is error message from Tomcat when I opened the problematic dashboard page again:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: airport.flight.control.servlet.DashboardServlet
```

I find this exception very weird, because this is the reference to class that I've just copied...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `WEB-INF/html/dashboard.html`?

Comment: Nope. The relative path should be from folder "web" as far as I see in other projects. I tried putting it into WEB-INF and updated path but it didn't help :(

Comment: Could you please share sample project example?